# How to solve Realloc(): invalid next size in c

Tags: c, realloc

I've been facing this error for quite some time now, and I'm stuck here. I was  creating a function that converts a sentence into an array of words, before processing them further, but the problem is that realloc is not looping more than 3 times. I.e., if i use a string of 3 words, the code runs fine, but if the sentence is more than 3 words, I'm stuck on this error

```
realloc(): invalid next size
zsh: IOT instruction  ./a.out
```

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char **process_str(char *str)
{
        char **str_ptr, **str_ptr2, *word_ptr,  word[20], chr;
        int i = 0, count = 0, ind = 0, len;
        bool first = true;

        if (str == NULL) return (NULL);
        str_ptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
        if (str_ptr == NULL) return (NULL);
        len = strlen(str) + 1;
        while (i < len)
        {
                chr = str[i];
                if ((chr == ' ' || chr == '\0') && ind > 0)
                {
                        word[ind] = '\0';
                        word_ptr = strdup(word);
                        if (first)
                        {
                                *(str_ptr) = word_ptr;
                                first = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                str_ptr2 = (char **)realloc(str_ptr, count + 1);
                                if (str_ptr2 == NULL) return (NULL);
                                *(str_ptr2 + count) = word_ptr;
                                str_ptr = str_ptr2;
                        }
                        ind = 0;
                        count++;
                        i++;
                        continue;
                }
                if (chr != ' ')
                {
                        word[ind] = chr;
                        ind++;
                }
                i++;
        }
        str_ptr2 = (char **)realloc(str_ptr, count + 1);
         if (str_ptr2 == NULL) return (NULL);
       *(str_ptr2 + count) = NULL;
       str_ptr = str_ptr2;
        return (str_ptr);
}
```

and i tested it using this function

```
int main(void)
{
        int i = 1;
        char **ptr, *s_ptr;
        char *str = "please please anf dsd  it for";

        ptr = process_str(str);
        printf("done step one\n");
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("ptr is NULL");
                return (1);
        }
        s_ptr = ptr[0];
        while (s_ptr != NULL)
        {
                printf("String: %s\n", s_ptr);
                s_ptr = ptr[i];
                i++;
        }
        return (0);
}
```

if i change the value of `str` in main, to something like `str = "This is home"` the code executes fine.
Please any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a buffer overflow. https://godbolt.org/z/h8Grb9bnK It looks like you're allocating the wrong amount of memory here: `str_ptr2 = (char **)realloc(str_ptr, count + 1);`. Should it be `sizeof(char*) * (count + 1)`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja is correct. You can also simplify quite a bit by setting the pointer null initially and using only `realloc`. It's documented to act like `malloc` if the input pointer is null.  Also in C you should not  cast the return value of either function. It's not necessary because the return value is `void*`, and it can mask some edge case errors.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The line two lines below the `realloc` makes me think that it should be `realloc(..., sizeof(char *)*(count+1))`.

Comment: So is the 'invalid next size' internal heap data and means 'you've corrupted the heap' (probably by writing outside the bounds of some object on the heap (allocated with won of the ?alloc() functions )